Coherence between associator and unitor in a monoidal category
I have a hard time trying to prove a coherence relation in a monoidal category. I'll start by giving the definition I'm working with:
A monoidal category is a sextuple $(C, \otimes, \mathbf{1}, \alpha, \lambda, \rho)$, where
$C$ is a category, $\otimes : C\times C\rightarrow C$ is a functor, $\mathbf{1}\in C$, and
$$
\begin{aligned}
&\alpha: \otimes \circ (\otimes\times \mathrm{Id})\rightarrow \otimes \circ (\mathrm{Id}\times \otimes)\\
&\lambda: \mathbf{1}\otimes - \rightarrow \mathrm{Id}\\
&\rho: -\otimes \mathbf{1} \rightarrow \mathrm{Id}.
\end{aligned}
$$
are natural isomorphisms, such that the pentagon and triangle diagrams commute for all $X,Y,Z,W\in C$:
$$
(1_X\otimes \lambda_Y)\circ \alpha_{X,\mathbf{1}, Y} =
\rho_X\times 1_Y
$$
$$
\alpha_{W,X,Y\otimes Z}\circ \alpha_{W\otimes X, Y, Z}
= (1_W\otimes \alpha_{X,Y,Z})\circ \alpha_{W,X\otimes Y,Z}
\circ (\alpha_{W,X,Y}\otimes 1_Z)
$$
Now, what I'm trying to prove is that $\lambda_X\otimes 1_Y =\lambda_{X\otimes Y}\circ\alpha_{\mathbf{1},X,Y}:(\mathbf{1}\otimes X)\otimes Y\rightarrow X\otimes Y$ for all $X,Y\in C$. I failed to find a way to incorporate the triangle and pentagon conditions to produce this identity.
So I ended up reading the proof given here (nlab) and I more or less understood the manipulations with the diagrams. However since this seems to me like a rather simple property that one would expect to hold, I wonder whether there is a more intuitive approach, or at least a more systematic way to go about proving this kind of coherence relations?

I just asked and answered this exact question over on MSE in the last two days, with some diagrams; here's the link. (That being said, I asked it over there originally because it's pretty basic stuff for monoidal categories.) That being said, I think the question at the end of your post about a systematic approach to coherence is a very good one; if you wanted to edit to make that the main focus of your question, it might be better received.

As far as systematicy goes you want Maclane’s coherence theorem, which should be discussed in any introduction to monoidal categories

@TimCampion Yes, but the more general question of how to systematically approach coherence issues in (potentially higher) categorical settings is less trivial, and I’d be interested to hear from people in e.g. computer science who use category theory and encounter what’s referred to as ‘coherence hell’.
